# jQuery FitVids, Tabs with mirror - YouTube disappears

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, youtube, fitvids

I'm trying to make a tab layout for different video mirrors.
Basically what I'm doing is a page with the main tab "Mirror 1" and a second one "Mirror 2".
The purpose is to make the video as big as possible inside the Tabs container using FitVids.

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Mirror 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Mirror 2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="video">
        <div id="tabs-1">{$data['record']['field_11_value']}</div>
        <div id="tabs-2">{$data['record']['field_15_value']}</div>
    </div>
</div>

jQuery(function($) {

$(document).ready(function(){
// Target your .container, .wrapper, .post, etc.
    $(".ipsBox").fitVids();
    $(".tabs").fitVids();
    $(".tabs-1").fitVids();
    $(".tabs-2").fitVids();
  });
});
    </script>
```

The first video (which is a Vimeo video) in the first tab works fine but the YouTube video in the second tab doesn't even show. Why?

Comment: What is the error you are getting, Do Inspect element.

Comment: No errors at all, that's the weird part :(

Comment: Now it shows up but like 800px further down on the page

Comment: If it is showing then, its a Css issue, check for styles.

Comment: I tested with a vimeo video inside the second tab, then it worked. It seems only to affect YouTube embeds. I looked around in the CSS but found nothing strange?

Comment: Check the CSS applied for YouTube...!

Comment: Nevermind! I placed the div blocks a bit weird and they overlapped eachother.
Shame.